# Wordpress: Author page PHP If viewing xxxx author page show this xxxxx

Tags: php, wordpress, author

I'm making custom author pages for a website with 3 authors. The page has a list of posts by the author, bio and social links.

I want to add a special feature that if it is certain's author page, lets say author id 8, it outputs some code. if not, do nothing. can someone please give me some advice on how to perform this conditional php call?

this is to add some information inside the php file with some details of the author.

Comment: `if ($author_id == 8) { echo 'something' }`?

Comment: I have set: 
`code
<?php if ($author_id == 8) { echo 'something' }?>
<?php endif; ?>
`
But the php file is not working anymomre... i'm missing something?

Comment: You need to define `$author_id` some place, this does not come from WordPress predefined.

Comment: and If I use the author name? would it work with this function?

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the `is_author()` function like this:

```
if( is_author('8'); ) {
    echo 'somehthing';
}
```

Comment: I have  added `code <?php if( is_author('mike-patton'); ) {
    echo 'somehthing';}?> ` but the code is broken  now the document is not showing... many thanks for helping.

Comment: No, its not working banago. I dont know why it seems to be broken... the page is all white. should I add something before/after?

Comment: You might have a PHP error. Go to wp-config.php and turn WP_DEBUG = true and see what it shows when you refresh again.

Comment: Blank screen after debug...nothing: no details about what's wrong...something in this code is not working...

Comment: if( is_author('8'); ) Please remove the semicolon here:

Comment: now it works!!! :) thanks and sorry for my ignorance. by the way do you create plugins for wordpress?? I need a custom php plugin

Comment: Yes I do. Contact me through my profile page if you want to talk.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the Codex documentation about conditional tags, you may find this specially useful: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#An_Author_Page

You can use those conditionals inside your author template to display the conditional information you want. In this case wnat you want is something like:

```
if (is_author( '8' ))
{
    //Do something cool
}
```

Hope it helps.